# ACF and or PHP content display

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am displaying the "Price" or an item on the page, only if the field is not empty or if the item is not "sold".

```php
<?php if(!empty(get_field('price')) && get_field('status') != 'Sold'): ?>
```

We now have a new status for Pending Payment items that we also want to hide the "price" of on the site. I have tried the below and some other variations but unable to get this to hide.

```php
<?php if(!empty(get_field('price')) && get_field('status') != 'Sold' || 'Pending Payment' ): ?>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use `in_array` for these kinds of things, especially because 2 items tends to grow to 3 or more eventually.

```php
if (!empty(get_field('price')) && !in_array(get_field('status'), ['Sold', 'Pending Payment'])):
```

The `empty` check isn't really needed, either, because string equality should fail anyways, too

```php
if (!in_array(get_field('status'), ['Sold', 'Pending Payment'], true)):
```